# How to insert multiple form data to database from jquery table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id = 1;

    $("#butsend").click(function() {
        $("#table1").append('<tr valign="top">\n\
            <td width="100px">' + (id++) + '</td>\n\
            <td width="100px">' + $("#sname").val() + '</td>\n\
            <td width="100px">' + $("#age").val() + '</td>\n\
            <td width="100px"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td>\n\
        </tr>');
    });

    var serializedData = $('#form1').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "save.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    $("#table1").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <label>Student Name</label><input type="text" name="sname" id="sname"></br>
    <label>Student Age</label><input type="text" name="age" id="age"></br>
    <input type="button" name="send" value="send" id="butsend"></br>
    <input type="button" name="save" value="Save" id="butsave"></br>
</form>

<table id="table1" name="table1" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th></th>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am adding multiple form data to table using jQuery.Then I want to send that added data to database table when click on save button.my sample code is here.
Can you help me.Thanks
http://jsfiddle.net/eruZC/3/

Comment: There is no difference between using ajax and using a normal form submission - your server-side database code will be basically the same.

Comment: But I want insert multiple row data when click on save button.How to insert multiple rows to database  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps which might mork.

- Assign **unique id** dynamically with script for **tr** and **td** tags for separation
- With unique id, just get the values of tr and td tags.
- Save the values in a **json** object and **POST** it to PHP.
- With PHP, save the values received from script to **Mysql** database .

Following the above steps,
Add this to your script tag

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var id = 1;  
    //Assigning id and class for tr and td tags for separation.

    $("#butsend").click(function() {
        var newid = id++; 
        $("#table1").append('<tr valign="top" id="'+newid+'">\n\
            <td width="100px" >' + newid + '</td>\n\
            <td width="100px" class="name'+newid+'">' + $("#sname").val() + '</td>\n\
            <td width="100px" class="age'+newid+'">' + $("#age").val() + '</td>\n\
            <td width="100px"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td>\n\
        </tr>');

    });

    var serializedData = $('#form1').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "save.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    $("#table1").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

   // crating new click event for save button

    $("#butsave").click(function() {
        var lastRowId = $('#table1 tr:last').attr("id"); //finds id of the last row inside table


        var name = new Array();  
        var age = new Array();   
        for ( var i = 1; i <= lastRowId; i++) {
            name.push($("#"+i+" .name"+i).html());  //pushing all the names listed in the table
            age.push($("#"+i+" .age"+i).html());   //pushing all the ages listed in the table
        }
        var sendName = JSON.stringify(name);  
        var sendAge = JSON.stringify(age);
        $.ajax({
            url: "save.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {name : sendName , age : sendAge},
            success : function(data){
                alert(data);    // alerts the response from php.
                }
        });
        });
});
```

Add this to PHP(**save.php**)

```
    <?php
$nameArr = json_decode($_POST["name"]);
$ageArr = json_decode($_POST["age"]);
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($nameArr); $i++) {

    if(($nameArr[$i] != "")){       //not allowing empty values and the row which has been removed.
    $sql="INSERT INTO table_name (Name, Age)
VALUES
('$nameArr[$i]','$ageArr[$i]')";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    }

}

Print  "All records added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Do you know how to get dynamic age value by row id from jquery table using jquery.

Comment: This is my code. I want to do is add all exam fees and display on total exam fee text box, when i add student to table.Then when i remove student from table the particular exam fee must be subtract from total fee.

Comment: hello @raduns do you have any idea about this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Need to return inserted value to the model as json type.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #table1 tr {
        vertical-align: top;
    }

        #table1 tr td {
            width: 100px;
        }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#butsend").click(function () {
            if (true) {//Check Validation
                $.ajax({
                    url: "save.php", type: "post",
                    data: $.param($('#form1').serializeArray()),
                    //data: JSON.stringify({}),//Pass json model
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#table1").append('<tr><td>' + data.model.id + '</td><td>' + data.model.sname + '</td><td >' + data.model.age
                            + '</td><td><a class="remCF" data-id="' + data.model.id + '">Remove</a></td></tr>');
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                    },
                    complete: function (msg) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $("#table1").on('click', '.remCF', function () {
            var $this = $(this).parents('tr');
            $.ajax({
                url: "remove.php", type: "post", dataTye: "json",
                data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
                success: function (data) {
                    $this.remove();
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                },
                complete: function (msg) {

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

this an below example for ASP.net mvc 3 calling controller action method

i do no how to return json result i php

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/controllername/actionmethodname"
});

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Add(News vm)
{
    using (var db = new Mvc3MDbContext())
    {
       //vm used contains id, name, etc
    }

    return Json(new { model = vm }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thank You,ThulasiRam. It's ok

Comment: Hello @ThulasiRam using your jquery code it's only update database table.not adding data to jquery table.

Answer (score 0):

when you click the add button you can also call php to connect to your database and then insert the form data. doing something similar to the php below should allow you to both insert into your database and still display in your table. A quick google can provide additional info on using php to connect to a database and interacting with it.

```
$("#butsend").click(function() {
    $("#table1").append('<tr valign="top">\n\
        <td width="100px">' + (id++) + '</td>\n\
        <td width="100px">' + $("#sname").val() + '</td>\n\
        <td width="100px">' + $("#age").val() + '</td>\n\
        <td width="100px"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td>\n\
    </tr>');

    <?php
        #connect to DB
        $con=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","database_name");
        #Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }      
        #what you want to insert into the database
        $query = "INSERT INTO table_name (table_field_id,table_field_name,table_field_age) VALUES ($id, name, age)";
        #insert into database
        mysqli_query($con,$query);
        #close database connection
        mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
});
```

Comment: Now I am doing this way.But if I remove row from display table,have to remove that row from database table also.how can do it.Thanks

Comment: it would work the same way. instead of passing an INSERT query you would remove the row from the database in based on the fields in your table matching the fields in your database (call it when you click the remove button). everything else in the php code could stay the same. the query would look something like 'DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value;'. Looking at your code it seems you iterate id so it would probably be your best choice for comparision when doing the delete.